# Should I instantiate the Num type class for a type that questionably fits the interface?

Tags: haskell

It seems to me that the `Num` type class consists of a pretty arbitrary collection of functions. There are lots of types that naturally have `+` and `*` operations, but are problematic as instances of `Num`, due to the presence of `abs`, `signum`, and `fromInteger`. I can't find any discussion of the design philosophy behind this class, so it's not clear to me if there is a sensible rationale here, or if it's an unfortunate historical oddity.

I'll give an illustration of my question. Suppose I'm implementing a `Matrix` class, with components that are `Double`s. I can obviously implement `+`, `*`, `-`, and `negate`. Maybe `fromInteger x` could give a 1x1 `Matrix` with component the `Double` value `fromInteger x`. It's less obvious what to do with `abs` and `signum`, but I could come up with something that satisfies the rule (from the class's documentation):

```
abs x * signum x == x
```

The objection to this idea is that my instance of `Num` is not fulfilling some implicit rules that people expect of `Num`. My `*` is a partial function (assuming the size of the `Matrix` is a runtime parameter), which is not true for the usual instances like `Double` and `Int`. And it doesn't commute. Whatever I come up with for `abs` and `signum` are not going to satisfy everyone's expectations.

The objection to this objection is that my `Matrix` multiplication is going to be a partial function anyway (and in this kind of type that seems to be accepted in the Haskell community), so why does it matter if it's `*` in particular that is the partial function? And if my `abs` and `signum` satisfy the rule from the documentation, then I've fulfilled my side of the bargain. Anyone relying on anything more from a `Num` instance is in the wrong.

Should a type like `Matrix` be an instance of `Num`?

Comment: `Num` is the class of numbers (including integers, floats, rational numbers etc.)... I wouldn't expect a Matrix to be a number.

Comment: Obviously `Num` is intended to be used for numbers. Mathematically (and apparently, programatically), it's less clear than one might think what is a number and what is not. Is `Num` supposed to only be for subrings of the complex numbers? That can't be right; there are lots of other rings that have a sensible `Num` implementation. I'm asking if the Haskell community has a consensus on what a number is for the purposes of `Num`.

Comment: It is my understanding (sorry, no references at present) that `Num` is a bit of a wart. It has been recognized time and time again (references?) that it should be replaced with a mathematically sound and thought-through hierarchy of typeclasses corresponding to various algebraic structures. As you've noticed, though, people haven't been able to agree on anything. I am bugged by this myself, and frequently find myself copying my own self-made such hierarchy. It is not nice, and has many problems. I really wish we could all agree on something compatible with mathematics :)

Comment: As for the question "should a type like `Matrix` be an instance of `Num`?": No, absolutely not, as it does not at all fit into the interface `Num` represents (never mind that that interface is poorly designed). You give a perfect example yourself.

Comment: @gspr: yeah, the [numerical prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) just is a bit to ambituous, too bulky to catch on. — IMO the `Num` class is actually not so bad (at least since it doesn't require `Show` anymore), it does exactly the right thing for the numerical types that are relevant for most users. For more advanced number-similar things it's not useful, but well... just don't write instances for those, then! There's no good reason to do so, as weaker classes are available that do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make `Num` instances for non-rings. It's just confusing.

Of course, you can often define instances which do *something useful*, but if it's not completely obvious *what* then better just define a plain function with descriptive name, or some weaker class instance with better-defined semantics. If somebody wants to use this with short operators or polymorphic `Num` functions, they can still define that locally in their own module (preferrably with a simple `newtype` wrapper.

In particular, a `Num`-instance for general (dynamically-sized) matrices is problematic because it's not obvious what should happen when the dimensions don't match. What behaviour do you want to generalise?

What I would consider a good instance is matrices of fixed quadratic size (i.e. linear endomorphisms on a given vector space). In this case, multiplication is evidently composition<sup>†</sup>, and number literals would be taken as constant-diagonal matrices, so `1` is actually multiplicative identity. Like what you write in maths contexts.

But that's not compatible with your idea of arbitrarily choosing the size of number-literals as 1×1! People would expect `2 * m` to work, but it crashes. Well, better crash than give unexpected results; unfortunately it's tempting to come up with some clever way of defining multiplication in a suitable way. For instance, we could block-diagonal-copy the smaller matrix until it's large enough, perhaps only do this in the 1×1 case... well, Matlab does this kind of ad-hoc stuff, but please! let's not take [such a horrible language](http://www.parallelnetz.de/ScriptingHater.html#MatLab) as a model for what's good ideas.

If you have something that's obviously an additive group, indeed vector space, then make it a [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html)! If you also have a multiplication, but it's partial, then better only define it as a plain function.

If you fancy, you can define instances for the fine finely staggered [numeric-prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) classes. Personally (though I like the idea of this project) I couldn't yet be bothered to use it anywhere, because it's rather an efford to understand the hierarchy.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Or is it*? Trouble already starts here, I think [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) actually implements `*` on matrices as element-wise multiplication. That's more horrible than Matlab!</sub>